# Sending a message from server to all clients

Tags: java, sockets, networking, client, server

I'm trying to code an instant messaging system... Initially, I'm doing it this way, and once I get it to work I'll add the GUI.

Once a client sends a message to the server, the server is supposed to display it to all the other clients. How can I do that? I've been trying a few things but it keeps displaying only to the client that sent the message...

Thanks in advance!

**SERVER**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class Server {
    //one per server
    static int port = 3000;
    private int backlog = 100;
    ServerSocket main;
    static DataOutputStream dataOut;
    static DataInputStream dataIn;
    static String scannerMessage;

    static BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    static class MailServer extends Thread {
        //one per client
        static int index;
        String name = Client.name;

        public MailServer(int index, DataInputStream in, DataOutputStream out) {
            Server.dataIn = in;
            Server.dataOut = out;
            this.index = index; // thread index, one per client
        }

        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    String receivedMessage = dataIn.readUTF();

                    //print receivedMessage to all clients

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public Server(int port) throws Exception {
        this.main = new ServerSocket(port);
    }

    // start a serve
    public void serve() throws Exception {
        int index = 1;
        while (true) {
            Socket socket = this.main.accept();
            InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
            OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
            DataInputStream dataIn = new DataInputStream(in);
            DataOutputStream dataOut = new DataOutputStream(out);

            // handle the connection
            // keep reading using an infintite loop
            System.out.println("Handling connection to Client " + index + "...");
            (new MailServer(index, dataIn, dataOut)).start();
            index += 1; // add one every time a new client is added
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Server s = new Server(port);
        System.out.println("Serving....");
        s.serve();
    }
}
```

**CLIENT**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class Client {

    static String hostname = "127.0.0.1";
    static int port = Server.port;
    static Socket socket;
    static String name;

    static class Sender extends Thread {
        DataOutputStream dataOut;
        public Sender(DataOutputStream dataOut) {
            this.dataOut = dataOut;
        }
        public void run() {
            while(true) {
                //get a message from the user
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); 
                try {
                    String message = br.readLine();
                    dataOut.writeUTF(message);
                    dataOut.flush();
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static class Receiver extends Thread {
        DataInputStream dataIn;
        public Receiver(DataInputStream dataIn) {
            this.dataIn = dataIn;
        }
        public void run() {
            while(true) {
                try {
                    //RECEIVE A MESAGE FROM THE SERVER (ending in \n)
                    String msg = dataIn.readUTF();
                    while (msg != null) {
                        System.out.println(msg);
                        msg = dataIn.readUTF();
                    }
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //client will require host name and the port
    public Client(String hostname, int port) throws Exception {
        socket = new Socket(hostname, port);
    }

    public void connect() throws Exception {
        InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
        OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
        DataInputStream dataIn = new DataInputStream(in);
        DataOutputStream dataOut = new DataOutputStream(out);

        //handle the connection
        System.out.println("Handling connection to server...");
        Thread sender = new Sender(dataOut);
        Thread receiver = new Receiver(dataIn);

        sender.start();
        receiver.start();

        sender.join();
        receiver.join();

        System.out.println("Client " + Server.MailServer.index);
        System.out.println("----------------------");
    }

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

            Client c = new Client(hostname, port);
            c.connect();
        }
}
```

*Update: I created a list of all the MailServer objects and then iterated through them to send the message to all the clients, as JP Moresmau suggested... but now the first Client to send something receives all the outputs. Why is this? How can I fix it... ? Thank you, and sorry if my questions seem too obvious or dumb, I'm still a Java noob:(*

**SERVER - UPDATED**

```
package csci2020_assignment51;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;


class Server {
    //one per server
    static int port = 3000;
    private int backlog = 100;
    ServerSocket main;
    static DataOutputStream dataOut;
    static DataInputStream dataIn;
    static String scannerMessage;

    static List<MailServer> mailServers = Collections.<MailServer>synchronizedList(new ArrayList<MailServer>());


    static BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    static class MailServer extends Thread {
        //one per client
        static int index;
        String name = Client.name;

        public MailServer(int index, DataInputStream in, DataOutputStream out) {        
            Server.dataIn = in;
            Server.dataOut = out;
            this.index = index; // thread index, one per client

        }

        public void run() { 
            while (true) {
                try {
                    String receivedMessage = dataIn.readUTF();
                    String outputMessage = "Client " + index + " said: " + receivedMessage;

                    //print receivedMessage to all clients
                    for (MailServer mailserver : mailServers) {
                        dataOut.writeUTF(outputMessage);
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public Server(int port) throws Exception {
        this.main = new ServerSocket(port);
    }

    // start a serve
    public void serve() throws Exception {
        int index = 1;
        while (true) {
            Socket socket = this.main.accept();
            InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
            OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
            DataInputStream dataIn = new DataInputStream(in);
            DataOutputStream dataOut = new DataOutputStream(out);

            // handle the connection
            // keep reading using an infintite loop
            System.out.println("Handling connection to Client " + index + "...");
            MailServer mailServer = new MailServer(index, dataIn, dataOut);
            mailServer.start();
            mailServers.add(mailServer);
            dataOut.writeUTF("Client " + index);
            index += 1; // add one every time a new client is added
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Server s = new Server(port);
        System.out.println("Serving....");
        s.serve();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a static list of all the MailServer objects you create

```
 static List<MailServer> servers=Collections.<MailServer>synchronizedList(new LinkedList<MailServer>);
 ...
 MailServer s=new MailServer(index, dataIn, dataOut);
 servers.add(s);
 s.start();
```

Then loop through them all when one of them receives a message, and for all expect the receiver, write the message to their output.

The big problem in your code is that dataOut and dataIn are unique! You need to move them to the MailServer class. Each MailServer talks to one specific client and hence needs to have their own streams.

```
static class MailServer extends Thread {
    DataOutputStream dataOut;
    DataInputStream dataIn;
```

And your notification loop becomes:

```
 for(MailServer mailServer:mailServers){
   if (mailServer!=this){
    mailServer.dataOut.writeUtf(...);
   }
 }
```

I also don't understand how you expect to get the Client.name in the server, since Client runs on another machine... Get rid of that for now.

Comment: Where should I place that portion of code? I've trying adding it in different places, but I keep getting errors :(

Comment: Well you add the servers to the list where you create them in the serve method... The list you define inside the Server class...